# Please explain m4 nested define in string

Tags: assembly, macros, processor, m4

I'm currently reading the book "SPARC Architecture, Assembly Language Programming, and C. Second Edition". I got to a place in the book, where I don't understand or am not able to comprehend a certain command:

```
 define(loc, 0)
 define(sto, 'loc:  44 $1 define('loc', eval(loc+2))')
```

The thing is, I do understand the first line. But I really don't understand the second argument of the 2nd line. The explanation in the book isn't helpful neither.

From the book:

> Here we have first defined a symbol, loc, to have the value 0. This symbol will represent the location counter, the memory address of the instruction being assembled. Each macro definition has been changed first to print the current value of loc and then to redefine loc to be loc plus the memory locations needed to store the instruction.
>
> The arguments to macros are characters and strings of characters, not numeric values. In redefining the value of loc we make use of another built-in macro eval. eval takes its string argument to represent an arithmetic expression. eval evaluates this expression and returns its value in the form of a numeric character string.

I know the above explanation may sound perfectly clear to you, but isn't to me. What I exactly don't understand is the part:  'loc:  44 $1 define('loc', eval(loc+2))'

I don't understand:

Why is this a string?

Why does loc have to be there?

Why, after defining 44 $1, is there another definition, "define('loc', eval(loc+2))'?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the task is to make an assembler using m4 macros. The expected output will be something like:

```
0000: 44 xx
0002: yy zz
...
```

That is, each line is prefixed with the address, followed by the machine code bytes.

The `loc:` at the start will print the current address for you, `44` is presumably the opcode for the `sto` instruction, and `$1` is the argument. The final part is redefining `loc` so that it points to the next available location. Since this instruction takes up two bytes, `loc` is incremented by 2.

Note that m4 uses backticks to start strings. You might have copied it incorrectly from the book.

Given this sample input:

```
define(loc, 0)
define(sto, `loc:  44 $1 define(`loc', eval(loc+2))')
sto(01)
sto(AA)
```

The output is:

```
0:  44 01
2:  44 AA
```

Comment: Alright, I guess now I got it, but why does the `loc:` in the beginning print the address? Is this the same `loc:`, that I defined a line before? Or is it an intern command?

Comment: Yes it's the same `loc`. It starts out from 0 (because that's how it's defined) then each macro adds the size of the instruction to it. In this example, `sto` is a 2 byte instruction, so `loc` is incremented by 2.

Comment: Ah, alright. It's funny how they expect you to know this already in the book. Whatever, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

In understanding *m4* you must stubbornly follow the logic *m4* follows.

Reading

```
define(loc, 0)
```

This is a macro and expands to nothing. There is a new line following and this new line remains.  Then it evaluates the parameters. *m4* looks up *loc*. **Fortunately** it isn't defined yet. If it was e.g.

```
define(loc, 0)

define(loc, 12)
```

then the second macro will execute after expansion

```
define(0, 12)
```

and the value of *loc* is still 0.
Normally you should escape the name of macros you want to define, so

```
define(`loc', 0)

define(`loc', 12)
```

Now the expansion of *loc* is indeed 12.
(This should make you weary about the knowledgeablity of the author of this book.)

Now the second line (corrected)

```
 define(`sto', 'loc:  44 $1 define('loc', eval(loc+2))')
```

*M4* evaluates the arguments

```
sto 
loc:  44 $1 define('loc', eval(loc+2))
```

Apparently sto is going to be a macro. The *define(st..* expands to merely a blank line.

Now look where *sto* is used, for example as it is called with an argument orangutan.

```
sto(`orangutan')
```

then m4 exands sto (assuming loc expands to 44)

```
0: 44 orangutan define(`loc', eval(44+2))
```

Pigheadely replacing loc with 44, whereever it is not escaped.
The define expands to nothing, but has the effect to give loc the value 46.
Thus the second line expands  (with side effects for *loc* ) to

```
0: 44 orangutan
```